# How can i configure products in wishlist

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, configurable-product, wishlist

When a user adds a configurable product in wishlist and when he visit the wishlist, he should be able to make changes to the product like size and color.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Wishlist
2. When you will hover product you can see **Edit** link.
3. Click on Edit link it's redirect to you on edit wishlist.
4. Change your Size and Color then click on **Update Wishlist** you can see your changes.

Comment: NO NO. I want this thing to appear on Wishlist page. The user should not go to product page to do so.

Comment: @avesh - No then you need to customize this wishlist feature as by default there is no option to do this

Comment: @hweb87 - +1 from my side - 45 secs late !!

Comment: So which which classes i need to touch ?

Answer (score 0):

When you add any configurable product with configurable option in the Wishlist.

**Its showing with that selected specific options.**

**But if you would like to edit those options - Magento have already given Edit Wishlist link below that specific product.**

**So when you click on Edit link - it will again go back to that specific product page , where you can choose another configrable options and then click on Update Wishlist.**

> **This will update your product wishlist and now it will shows updated**
>   **options**.

Comment: NO man i want it to be happen on wishlist page. I don't want my users to go back to product page and edit then come back.

Comment: Can it happen on same page?

Comment: @avesh - Yes it can happen on the same page , but you need to customize it - and it requires wishlist modules customization

Comment: Ya, Can you help in this?

Comment: Which which classes i need to modify?